# How to generate error log to fix crashes

Tags: linux, debugging, error-handling, stack-trace

Many applications generate an error log when they crash, which makes it easy to find the bug. To achieve the same, I used Linux signal handling to catch segmentation faults. I used **[stacktrace.h](http://code.google.com/p/projection-errors/source/browse/stacktrace.h)** to generate trace:

```
void sigsegvHandler(int)
{
  signal(SIGABRT, 0);
  signal(SIGSEGV, 0);
  FILE * errorLog;
  errorLog = fopen ("/tmp/myapp.log" , "w");
  qDebug() << "\n\n*************************************************************\n";
  qDebug() << "Catching SIGSEGV, please report a bug at http://mysite.com/bugs
  qDebug() << "MyApp version: " << "1.0-1" << "\n";
  print_stacktrace(errorLog);
  fclose(errorLog);
  raise(SIGSEGV);
}
```

But the trace generated, hardly speaks anything about the crash. Isn't it possible to generate the trace which points to line number in code where the crash occurred, if we are using debug version of our application, as happens when we use gdb.